# Soapui manipulation of json response

Tags: json, soapui

I am using SoapUI to test restful web services.
I have a test step which returns a json response like..

```
{
  "createdUser": "CRINFO",
  "createdDate": 1254413167000,
  "updatedUser": "62041",
  "updatedDate": 1452105085000,
  "sourceSystem": "CIS",
  "versionNumber": 47,
  "crimeNo": "000037P/09",
  "furtherInvestigation": false
```

}

I wish to use this response in the body of the next test step request but I want to manipulate a few of the properties first. 
e.g. set the furtherInvestigation property to TRUE.

```
{
      "createdUser": "CRINFO",
      "createdDate": 1254413167000,
      "updatedUser": "62041",
      "updatedDate": 1452105085000,
      "sourceSystem": "CIS",
      "versionNumber": 47,
      "crimeNo": "000037P/09",
      "furtherInvestigation": true
}
```

I have created a property transfer step and have managed to get the entire response to transfer to the next test step in the request body but can't figure out how to change the property.
In the property transfer step I have the following selections..
Source:previousTestStep Property:Response Path Language:JsonPath
Target:NextTestStep Property:Request Path Language:JsonPath

Whats the best way to do this? I have researched this problem and discovered groovy scripts that could possibly do what I want but thought there must be an easier way.
Many thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: It appears that the json response is not a valid one. More over, the value you intended to change is already false. Any way, it can be done even without property transfer, but the optimum way would depend on how much data change is needed. Can you please provide more details?

Comment: Hi. I meant change the further investigation property to true and also have removed a lot of the json for easy viewing but the principal should be the same. At most I need to amend 3 or 4 properties..

Comment: can you edit the question and format the json to have at least a valid one with example where it needs to changed?

Comment: It looks that you still need most of the data from previous response and some of the data will be changed. Is it based any condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this with following steps.

1) Add script assertion for the source test step

2) Add the below lines in script assertion

```
def response = messageExchange.responseContent
response = response.replace("'furtherInvestigation': false","'furtherInvestigation': true")
messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.setPropertyValue("jsonResponse",response)
```

3) For destination test step, keep ${#TestCase#jsonResponse} for request body instead of actual request body

Answer (score 1):

If you like to do in Groovy, you can use these steps

1. Use `JsonSlurper` to parse Json
2. Manipulate Json

3.Build Json again

```
  def builder = new JsonBuilder(your_changed_json)
  def json = builder.toPrettyString()
  json = groovy.json.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(json)
```

4. set the above json to your request

   ```
   step.testRequest.setRequestContent(json)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this.. I used a combination of your answer and Ramu's. I inserted a script assertion on the test step that generated the response and using groovy changed the property value and set it to a parameter which you can then use in the next test step as the request body.

Comment: import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
def response = messageExchange.responseContent
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
jsonSlurper.furtherInvestigation = true
jsonSlurper.oic = '97001'
def jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder(jsonSlurper)
log.info(jsonBuilder)
messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.setPropertyValue("jsonResponse",jsonBuilder.toString())